# Facing issue in chart size while I am trying to use billboard.js chart library with Angular 6

Tags: angular, charts, billboard.js

I am trying to use billboard.js chart library with Angular 6 and facing issue in chart size. When the page load for first time, chart size is bigger than it's div container and when i change browser window size, chart's size is automatically adjusted according to div container.

See the screenshot before and after window resize.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

I have tried to lazy load graph as mentioned [here](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.render), but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a stackblitz demo ?

Comment: @abd995 here is the link for reproducing error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whkwcr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html here Angular 8 is used, but in our development environment, we are using Angular 6. Both have problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `AfterViewInit` and add this method to the class. This line of code resizes the chart after the chart is rendered.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.charts[0].resize();    
}
```

You can also specify height and width to the resize function to resize chart to a specific size.

```
resize({height: '200px', width: '400px'});
```

Check the documentation here - https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Chart.html#resize